# ssrs combining rows into result set

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, group-by, pivot

So I have a sql server 2005 query that returns results like so:

```
Address | Doctor
-----------------------
1         Dr A
1         Dr B
1         Dr C
2         NULL
3         NULL
4         Dr D
4         Dr E
5         Dr F
```

What I want is to get the output so that when I render the report I have them grouped together:

```
Dr A
Dr B
Dr C
Address1

Address2

Address3

Dr D
Dr E
Address4

Dr F
Address5
```

The problem is right now in my SSRS report I group by Address and it is only listing the first Dr and if the location has more then 1 Dr then they are not being listed.

Comment: can you post the rest of the columns as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to do this on the sql side (which was required to render the report correctly) I had to use Coalesce which my exact situation was detailed in this link:

[Coalesce example grouping up multiple rows](http://www.sqlprof.com/blogs/sqldev/archive/2008/03/31/how-to-list-multiple-rows-of-data-on-same-line.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Starting out, it looks like you have a LEFT join between the Doctors and the Address.

I think you should group by Doctor and put the Address into the detail section and they should all appear properly.

Comment: This suggestion works but for my report I needed every result to exist within 1 row of the SSRS table so that when the .pdf is generated each address is kept together and not spanned on different columns of the report.

Answer (score 1):

You can use group on property of ssrs..

If u have all the fields(address and doctor in ur example) on a table.. right click the table row and in the group on section, write the following (=Fields!Doctor.value) which says group by Doctor

It acts as a (group by) in sql.